# Three.js - Sprites and light

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm implementing a little 3D maze game, rendering the walls as Meshes affected by a PointLight. Some objects will be implementes as Sprites, but I'm having an issue....the objects appear fully iluminated, a behavior like MeshBasicMaterial.

It's possible to have these Sprites affected by the light just like Lambert or Phong materials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a Sprite, why not use a PlaneGeometry with a MeshLambertMaterial, and keep the rotation of the plane in sync with the rotation of the camera so that the plane always faces the camera just as a Sprite does? See the related question [Three.js - billboard effect, maintain orientation after camera pans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731293/three-js-billboard-effect-maintain-orientation-after-camera-pans) for further details.

Comment: @Leprosy This answer does not answer the question you asked: "Is it possible to have these Sprites affected by the light just like Lambert or Phong materials?". This is a suggestion for a work-around using `PlaneGeometry`. Perhaps you should change your question to match the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Having `Sprite`s respond to lights is currently not supported. They are affected by `Fog`, however.

three.js r.62

Comment: OMG...I think I will have to find another way to implement my objects. Thanks!