# ThreeJS - Object to LookAt Camera so it's always 100% straight/flat

Tags: javascript, three.js, trigonometry

Lpoking at this example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdmMPW, I have a camera orbiting around a sphere and I want to have some text labels/satellites (represented by the plane object) to always face the camera.

```
function render() {
 marker.lookAt(camera.position);
  renderer.clear();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

I'm using  `marker.lookAt(camera.position)`; on the render loop, but the plane starts to appear on an angle when you move the mouse up and down. I want it so it's always 100% straight for the user and never slanted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731293/three-js-billboard-effect-maintain-orientation-after-camera-pans

Comment: amazing thanks!!! I've been stuck on that for ages! :D

Answer (score 0):

That's because Object3D.lookAt works in 3D space. What you need to use is THREE.Sprite http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Objects/Sprite, that will make sure the billboard is always correctly facing the camera.